# MongoDB - Find array index of document in array field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have aggregation that contains array field. This array field contains documents (objects). For these I have some matching criteria and I would like create a new fields named `lowestCheapIndex` and `highestExpensiveIndex`, each with array index of matching element.

**Matching criteria:**

`lowestCheapIndex` - Should contain **lowest** array index number of any record item, that has price below 20.

`highestExpensiveIndex` - Should contain **highest** array index number of any record item, that has price over 30.

**My current aggregation output:**

```js
{
    '_id': 'Egg shop',
    'records': [
        {'_id': 1, 'price': 22},
        {'_id': 2, 'price': 18},
        {'_id': 3, 'price': 34},
        {'_id': 4, 'price': 31},
        {'_id': 5, 'price': 13},
    ]
}
```

**Desired output:**

```js
{
    '_id': 'Egg shop',
    'records': [
        {'_id': 1, 'price': 22},
        {'_id': 2, 'price': 18},
        {'_id': 3, 'price': 34},
        {'_id': 4, 'price': 31},
        {'_id': 5, 'price': 13},
    ],
    'lowestCheapIndex': 1,
    'highestExpensiveIndex': 3,
}
```

**Question:**

How can i retrieve array index based on my criteria? I found `$indexOfArray` in docs, but still I am having hard time how it would be used in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following in an aggregation pipeline:

1. use `$map` to augment your `records` array with booleans indicating below 20 and over 30
2. use `$indexOfArray` to search for the booleans; For `highestExpensiveIndex`, reverse the array first to get the index then subtract it from size of array - 1 to get the expected index.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "records": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$records",
          "as": "r",
          "in": {
            "_id": "$$r._id",
            "price": "$$r.price",
            "below20": {
              $lt: [
                "$$r.price",
                20
              ]
            },
            "over30": {
              $gt: [
                "$$r.price",
                30
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "lowestCheapIndex": {
        "$indexOfArray": [
          "$records.below20",
          true
        ]
      },
      "highestExpensiveIndex": {
        "$subtract": [
          {
            "$subtract": [
              {
                $size: "$records"
              },
              {
                "$indexOfArray": [
                  {
                    "$reverseArray": "$records.over30"
                  },
                  true
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PWjuSTbkGKO)

Comment: Thanks for posting solution. `lowestCheapestIndex` should be `1` (record with _id: 2), because array indexes are beginning by `0` not `1`. In contrary, `highestExpensiveIndex` should be the highest index. That means `3` (record with _id: 4). Thanks for code snippet, but it shows only the **lowest** array index for `below20` and **lowest** array index for `over30`.

Comment: The answer is updated with explanation. New solution uses `$reverseArray`

Comment: just in case... would you mind to edit your answer and to paste code directly here as well? This is due external content having possibility of being deleted after some period of time.